# How to position tooltip when moving along y-axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image: Please refere image]

When I try to hover mouse along `y-axis` I observed that the `tooltip` is at the top but the point selected is at the bottom of the graph. This is because the point below might be the second point when we hover along the `x-axis`.
How do I make `highcharts` transverse points along the `y-axis` ?

**Note:** It is not a shared tooltip

I have tried setting the following attributes in the tooltip:

```
followPointer: true,
followTouchMove: true,
```

Comment: Hi @Pri_stack, Could you reproduce that problem in some online code editor? In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bsp18odx/ everything works fine.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the prompt response. Following is the fidlle link 
https://jsfiddle.net/3m29ycxt/1/

 You will observe that if you place the mouse cursor on the top left corner the point at the very bottom is highlighted and as i start moving the mouse cursor in the vertical direction random points start to highlight. why is that happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of the default value of the `findNearestPointBy` option, which is `'x'`. You can set it to `'y'` or `'xy'`:

```
series: [{
    findNearestPointBy: 'xy',
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2nqdxp3z/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.findNearestPointBy

Comment: Thanks a ton ...! :)